# How to implement mutiple http request in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, token

I using spring security and jwt . I want login two way : One way by email, password and one way by phone and passcode. If user login by email when login success spring auto return token to user. It same way when user login by phone. I has write code login by email and it login by success and token return to user but i can't know how to implement by phone and passcode. When i implement by mutiple http login form, spring throw me error look like :

```
  Field authenticationManager in com.baotrung.controller.JwtAuthenticationController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
        - emailAuthenticationManager: defined by method 'authenticationManagerBean' in class path resource [com/baotrung/config/MultipleSecurityConfig$ApiConfigurationAdapter.class]
        - PhoneAuthenticationManager: defined by method 'authenticationManagerBean' in class path resource [com/baotrung/config/MultipleSecurityConfig$PhoneConfigurationAppter.class]


    Action:

    Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Bellow my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultipleSecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
            // user for matching credentials
            // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
            auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }


        @Bean(name = "emailAuthenticationManager")
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            // We don't need CSRF for this example
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    // dont authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                    // store user's state.
                            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(100)
    public static class PhoneConfigurationAppter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private JwtUserPhoneDetailsService jwtUserPhoneDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private JwtPhoneRequestFilter jwtPhoneRequestFilter;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
            // user for matching credentials
            // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
            auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserPhoneDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }


        @Bean(name = "PhoneAuthenticationManager")
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            // We don't need CSRF for this example
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    // dont authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/phone/authentication", "/phone/register").permitAll().
                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                    // store user's state.
                            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtPhoneRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }


}
```

Entity

**User**

```
  public class UserDTO {
        private String username;
        private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

PhoneUser

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_phone")
public class PhoneUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String phone;
    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String passcode;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPasscode() {
        return passcode;
    }

    public void setPasscode(String passcode) {
        this.passcode = passcode;
    }
}
```

EmailJwtTokenFilter

```
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

PhoneJwtTokenFilter

```
@Slf4j
public class PhoneJwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

    authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
            .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user) throws Exception {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsService.save(user));
}

private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    } catch (DisabledException e) {
        throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
    }
}
```

I have a question. I need create two class OnePerRequestFilter for email and phone or only one request for both OnePerRequestFilter? . Why spring thow exception **authenticationManagerBean** ? . And how to impement user login two way : one way in email and one way in phone in same spring security . Thanks you